# Treating View in another ViewController as a UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller that I set up in storyboard that's quite complicated; it consists of a scrollView, tableView, another uiview, etc. What I want to be able to do is animate the viewController..but the animations I want to do are much much easier with a UIView. I tried recreating all of the elements of the view in the an .xib file, but it became too messy/complicated.

Anyway, is there anyway I can treat the entire "view" in the second view controller as a UIView?

Comment: Sure, add all of the view's subviews to a larger "container" UIView and manipulate that, or manipulate the view controller's parent `view`.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What kind of animations do you want to do?

Comment: @JAL how would I manipulate the parents `view`? Suppose I have 

`class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

}` where all my code is stored right now. How would I reference this view in another view controller?

Comment: @andlin I want to have an animation where the view slides up and then the user can swipe down on the view to close it. Originally I had the view opening modally (fine) but closing it with the gesture seemed to be incredibly hard.

Comment: @andlin I also wanted to add other characters to the view controller such as shadow, change the size, etc. Not sure if I could do that with a normal view controller. What do you think?

Comment: You seem to confuse the purpose of views and view controllers, basically views handles the presentation and the viewcontrollers the interaction and logic surrounding views. Can' you just use one viewcontroller? You then show/hide your other view in the viewcontroller's view using the animations you want.